# 3D transform: Weird infinitely spinning duplicated Img

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been learning Java script, I was trying to make a Memory (Find the pair) game. When this bug happened. I know that this probably isn't the best way to write the project but I wasn't able to fix this for straight 5 hours.

I tried sitting a time out period between the two statement in which I flip elements using the array, This arguably made it happen way less. I really don't know why JS behaved that way.

```js
 var arr = [];
     var flipped = [];
     function aniFlip(elem){
         elem.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
         var i = 0;
         var id = setInterval(frame, 3);
         function frame(){
             if(elem.style.transform  == 'rotateY(90deg)'){
                 elem.style.display = 'none';
                 clearInterval(id);
             }else{
                 i++;
                 elem.style.transform  = 'rotateY('+ i.toString()+ 'deg)';
             }
         }
         var elem2 = (elem == elem.parentElement.lastElementChild) ? (elem.previousElementSibling) : (elem.nextElementSibling);
         setTimeout(function(){  elem2.style.display = 'block';
        elem2.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
         var t = 90;
         var ic = setInterval(frame2, 3);
         function frame2(){
             if(elem2.style.transform  == 'rotateY(0deg)'){
                 elem2.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
                 clearInterval(ic);
             }else{
                 t--;
                 elem2.style.transform  = 'rotateY('+ t.toString()+ 'deg)';
             }
         } }, 450);
     }
     function control(elem){
         switch(flipped.length){
             case 0:
                 flipped.push(elem.parentElement.lastElementChild);
                 aniFlip(elem);
                 break;
             case 1:
                 if(flipped[0] != undefined && elem.parentElement.lastElementChild != flipped[0]){
                flipped.push(elem.parentElement.lastElementChild);
                 aniFlip(elem);
                     setTimeout(function(){if(flipped[0].src != flipped[1].src){
                         aniFlip(flipped[0]);
                         aniFlip(flipped[1]);
                     }setTimeout(function(){flipped = [];}, 540)}, 540);
                     
                 }
                 
                 break;
             default:
                 break;
         }
     }
    function setImages(){
        arr = [];
        var e = document.getElementById("select");
       var nImg= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var myNode = document.getElementById("Game");
        myNode.innerHTML ='';
        for(var i = 0; i < nImg; i++){
            arr.push(i);
            arr.push(i);
        }
        arr.sort(function(a,b){return 0.5 - Math.random()});
        var text = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < nImg*2; i++){
            text += '<div class="memcontainer"><img src="images/back.png" class="memcardsf">\n<img src="images/cards/'+ arr[i].toString() +'.jpg"  class="memcardsb"></div>\n';
        }
        nCols = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(nImg*2));
        while((nImg*2)%nCols != 0){
            nCols++;
        }
        nRows = (nImg*2)/nCols;
        myNode.innerHTML = text;
        var con = document.getElementsByClassName('memcontainer');
        for(i = 0; i < con.length; i++) {
            con[i].style.width= (100/nCols).toString() + "%" ;
            con[i].style.height = (100/nRows).toString() + "%" ;
            con[i].firstChild.addEventListener("click",function(){ control(this);});
            con[i].lastChild.addEventListener("click", function(){ control(this);});
        }
        
    }
```

```css
html{
        background: url(images/dark_background_2-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    html, body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
       height : 100%;
    }
    #titleContainer{
        position: relative;
        width : 100%;
        height: 140px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #titleContainer span{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        width:830px;
        padding:2%;
        margin: auto;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 70px;
        color: white;
        font-family: Courier New;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px white, -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black;
    }
    #brain{
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        height:150px;
    }
    #Game{
        float: left;
        width:800px;
        height: 800px;
        border: 10px inset white;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black, -5px -5px 10px black;
    }
    #controls{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-content: center;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        top: 200px;
        left: 40px;
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
        background-color: #73AD21;
        border-radius: 100px 30px 100px 30px;
        padding: 40px;
        transition: width 1s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px black, -2px -2px 10px black;
    }
    #container{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    #select{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        top: 20%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
        padding: 16px 20px;
    }
    #button{
        position: relative;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        background-color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius:10px;
        color: black;
        padding: 16px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
.memcontainer{
    position: relative;
    width: 0%;
    height: 0%;
    padding: 4px;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

.memcardsf{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    transform: rotateY(0);
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px white, -2px -2px white, -2px 2px white, 2px -2px white;

    
}
.memcardsb{
    display: none;
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px white, -2px -2px white, -2px 2px white, 2px -2px white;
    
}
.memcardsf:hover{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(240, 255, 0, 0.8), -4px -4px 4px rgba(240, 255, 0, 0.8), -4px 4px 4px rgba(240, 255, 0, 0.8), 4px -4px 4px rgba(240, 255, 0, 0.8) ;
}
    #container::after{
        content : '';
        clear: both;
        display:block;
    }
    #titleContainer span{
        animation-name: title;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards
    }
    #brain{
        animation-name: brain;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    #Game, #controls{
        animation-name: game;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    @keyframes game{
        from{transform: scale(0);}
        to{transform: scale(1);}
    }
    @keyframes brain{
        from{transform: translate(0 ,-45px) scale(0);}
        to{transform: translate(0 ,-45px) scale(1);}
    }
    @keyframes title{
        from{transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);}
        to{ transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);}
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:1388px){
        #controls{
            left:20px;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:1317px){
        #controls{
            width:300px;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:1152px){
        #controls{
            width:200px;
        }
    }
   @media screen and (max-width:1036px){
        #container{
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #controls{
            position: relative;
            top: 10px;
            width: 400px;
        }
        
    }
```

```html
<body onload="setImages()">
<div id="titleContainer">*
    <span><img id="brain" src='images/brain.png'>The Memory Game</span>
</div>
<div id="container">
<div id="Game">
    
</div>
<div id="controls">
<select id="select" name="pairs" onchange="setImages()">
  <option value="18">18 pair</option>
  <option value="21">21 pair</option>
  <option value="24">24 pair</option>
   <option value="28">28 pair</option>
    <option value="32">32 pair</option>
</select>
 <button id="button" type="button" >Reset</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I would have hoped it wouldn't do this. The flipping function works perfectly but once I implemented control this happened.

First Image:
[image: First Image]

The duplicated image is the back side of the card

Second Image:
[image: Second Image]

can be seen here rotating, It is the same image but I took pictures from 2 different tries.

Edit: One thing I did before this is I disable mouse clicks during the animation this fixed my Flip function but still once I Implemented control this happened

Edit: I just noticed that deceleration in the setTimeout function of the function called aniFlip seem to execute at the same time as the beginning of the function regardless of the time period